Surpringly difficult conversion from multi-line string to Pandas dataframe
I used a chatgpt AI assistant to pull data from a PDF which it did successfully. However I am struggling to convert this string output to a Python dictionary, though the ultimate goal is to make it a pandas data-frame.
The type(result) = str and if I print(result) the output is:
```python
{
  'ReportDate': '11/30/2022',
  'BankName': 'Bank ABC',
  'Key 1': 194820,
  'Key 2': 24778,
  'Key 3': 1281778,
  'Key 4': 10943806,
  'in_thousands': True,
  'ReportName':'Report1'
}
```

Both ast.literal_eval(result), eval(result) aren't working.
Attempts and result:
Attempt 1:
y = eval(result)

Attempt 2:
import ast
result = message_content.value
temp_result =  result.replace('python', '', 1).strip()
result_dict = ast.literal_eval(temp_result)

Both attempts result in a SyntaxError: invalid syntax pointing to
```python
^


You need to remove the code fences before you try to parse it.

So remove the first and last lines, then call ast.literal_eval() on the rest.

It would probably be helpful if you explained how you obtained this string output, @nicholaswood. As user Barmar correctely points out, you could turn that string back into a Python object, but it seems likely that you didn't need to cause this much trouble for yourself in the first place. Another very straightforward solution (if you just copied and pasted that content) would be to simply assign the inner text to a variable in a Python script or on a REPL, since it is valid Python.

The content wasn't copy pasted the content is a string output was obtained from a chatgpt file searcher api assistant. It is the value stored in message content.
messages = list(client.beta.threads.messages.list(thread_id=thread.id, run_id=run.id))
message_content = messages[0].content[0].text


ChatGPT is returning markdown, not just the python code.

Thanks everyone, I appreciate the responses and additional information. I added an answer below based on the replies and what worked.

I definitely overthought it, it was as simple as the whole text block being a string and the triple quotes were just characters in the string. So like suggested in comments, it was just a matter of removing the word python, the triple quotes and new line characters and converting using ast.literal_eval().
    result = message_content.value
    result = result.replace("```python", "").replace("```", "").replace('\n', '').strip()
    result_dict = ast.literal_eval(result)

